# "Developed to [infinitive]" vs. "developed for [gerund]"

Tags: verbs, writing-style, infinitives, gerunds, to-for

I am confused about when to use "to verb" and when to use "for verb+ing" constructs.
For example what would be the proper construct for the following sentences extracted from scientific journals:

> A chemically reactive Raman probe with femtomolar sensitivity was developed for monitoring/to monitor ROS generated in living cells.

Another example:

> As the metabolism products,ROS are very important in cell signaling and homeostasis to regulate/for regulating a whole wide range of biological functions.

Which construct should be used and when?

Comment: In those cases, there is no difference. Both constructions identify the **purpose** of the probe, and ROS, respectively; and among the many varieties of purpose clauses are _for_ + `gerund`, and _to_ + `infinitive`. No difference in meaning. It is usually the case that one can use several different constructions with the same sense; the choice is the speaker's.

Comment: I would personally develop something to do something and use it for something. Second sentence similarly, it is important to regulate so the metabolism uses something for regulating... I can see it vice versa, but my personal taste is what I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be a slight difference between...

> y for fooing n
>
> y to foo n

In the first case, 'for fooing n', y is contributing to n, either by complement or composition, but not necessarily the primary or controlling subject or activity.

In the second case, 'to foo n', y is the primary or controlling subject of the activity.

Another example might demonstrate this a bit more clearly:

> I use a toothbrush for brushing my teeth.
>
> **I use a toothbrush to brush my teeth.**
>
> **I use toothpaste for brushing my teeth.**
>
> I use toothpaste to brush my teeth.

In these examples, it should be clear which is optional for the activity, but strongly advised, and which is essential.